# Remapped Commands only work in some windows

Tags: autohotkey

I have a new keyboard that has a split spacebar, backspace on left thumb, space on right thumb.  Before getting this keyboard, I was using the short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open Launchy.
With this new keyboard, I would ALSO like to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

I added the following mapping to AutoHotKey

```
^!BS::
MsgBox Working
SendInput ^!{Space}
return
```

If I have certain windows open (say Notpad), pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shows the message box, and then launches the program as expected (the Launchy binding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is controlled by it's own options UI stuff).  However, certain windows (e.g. Powershell) seem to swallow the SendInput part, so I will see the message box, but Launchy will not open.

What can I do to get AutoHotKey to send it's commands into the regular message queue instead of to the active window.

**Note:**  I have already tried using various different combinations, but it doesn't seem to work.

*Edit: Thanks to MCL for suggesting WinActivate which led me in the right direction.  Full details below*

**Solution:**

```
^!BS::
DetectHiddenWindows, on
WinActivate, Launchy
SendInput ^!{Space}
return
```

For some reason, certain apps were swallowing the keyboard shortcuts being generated by AHK.  So Launchy never received them and didn't launch.  However, [DetectHiddenWindows](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DetectHiddenWindows.htm) and [WinActivate](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) followed by the regular keyboard shortcut seems to work.

Comment: Play around with combinations of `#UseHook` and `#InstallKeybdHook`. Put them at the top of your script. Also, you could consider just running it directly like `Run, path\to\launchy.exe`.

Comment: Same comment as below, but this is not a shortcut to launch the app, it's a hotkey defined in the app to bring it into focus.  The app is already running and is minimized to the tray.

Comment: How about using [WinActivate](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) instead?

Comment: Success!... kind of.  So I managed to get it to work, WinActivate being one important step. :)  If you submit an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Good to hear. But sounds like not everything's cut and dried. If you want to know something else, post a new question or ask in the comments.

Comment: I added the details of how I got it to work in my question above.  I didn't know if it was good form to answer my own question.  I got it working, it just seemed a little hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using native AHK code to activate a window is usually the preferable option as opposed to sending keys somewhere. `WinActivate` will do what you want. However, you'll have to choose a suitable identifier for your window. Inspect the window with Window Spy; normally, the window class (`ahk_class`) is a good option. If your application only has one window, AHK_L's `ahk_exe` will be a good choice too.

Your code could look like this:

`!BS::WinActivate, ahk_exe launchy.exe`

Comment: The main reason for not doing it this way was that I don't have any information about the window.  It's not just in the back, it's actually hidden, so I can activate the window and Window Spy shows that it's the active window, but it's still not visible.  I know that it's the active window because if I type and hit enter, the command executes as expected, I just can't see the window.

Sending keys also has the extra benefit that hitting the shortcut again dismisses the window just like I would expect when using the shortcut configured in the app.

Comment: @BenRandall Use an additional `WinShow`.